# Increment value in dictionary for each key ocurrence

Tags: python

How do I implement a counter in python so that, for each unique key in a dictionary, its corresponding value increments by 1? The output should look something like this:

```
192.168.164.92 : 4
192.168.164.91 : 2
192.168.164.93 : 8
192.168.164.84 : 5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Answer (score 0):

### How to increment value in dictionary for each key ocurrence

```
ips = {"192.168.164.92" : 4,
       "192.168.164.91" : 2,
       "192.168.164.93" : 8,
       "192.168.164.84" : 5}

new_ips = ["192.168.164.92", "192.168.164.91", "192.168.164.93", "192.168.164.84"]

for ip in new_ips:
    if not ip in ips:
        ips[ip] = 1
    else:
        ips[ip] += 1
        
print(ips)

>{'192.168.164.92': 5, '192.168.164.91': 3, '192.168.164.93': 9, '192.168.164.84': 6}
```